# Why identity_insert changed to OFF

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My database was working perfectly fine until I added this code to my model (ID)

```
[Key]
[Column(Order = 0)]
```

After I added this I started getting the error that

```
identity_insert is set to off
```

Therefore I had change it to this

```
[Key]
[Column(Order = 0)]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

**So my question is why does `[Column(Order = 0)]` cause the Auto-increment to switch off?**

Comment: do you want to use a composite primary key?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are trying to assign a value explicitly to a column where the database automatically assigns it.

The error is because you made this property as Primary Key so now the database will be responsible to insert the Identity and for you it will be Identity Insert off.

Comment: That's the thing though. I wasn't trying to assign anything to it. It only turned off when I added `[Column(Order = 0)]`

Comment: are you not assigning value to your Key property anywhere in your application?

Comment: I have 2 key properties. The ID[Key] does not have anything assigned to it as that is down to the database